# Is "an" necessary before "idiom"?

Tags: grammar, idioms

It is an "idiom".

OR

It is "idiom".

Which is correct? Is "an" necessary before "idiom"?

Comment: Context context context. "Idiom" is one of many more-or-less abstract words which can be uncountable (referring to a general phenomenon) or countable (referring to a particular instance of that phenomenon). In some contexts only one of them makes sense; in other contexts, both are possible. What is your context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When describing a phrase as an idiom, "It is an idiom" is correct. This is likely to be the most common usage by far. I suspect this is what you were trying to understand.

However, there are situations when you can imagine the other phrase being correct, although it would require very specific context such as:

A: Is the answer to the question "idiom"?
B: Yes. It is "idiom".

Comment: Or for a more natural example: "Discuss the use of idiom in *Huckleberry Finn*."

Comment: Yes that’s a better example.

Comment: **Which idiom** are we discussing? Is it **the idiom** about article use?

Comment: @Davo it’s not clear in the OP’s post so I gave an example of each.

Comment: Actually, my comment was illustrating two more uses. :)

Comment: Of course! :) very good!